# Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[String : Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, xcode8

I have a POST body paramter like this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "contactInfo": "string",
  "message": "string"
}
```

So since i am using the Alamofire for posting the parameters i am describing the post body dictionary like this:

```
let body = ["id": userID, "name": userName, "contactInfo": contactInfo, "message": message]

class func postUserFeedback(userID: Int, userName: String, contactInfo: String, message: String,completionHandler: @escaping (FeedbackResponse?) -> Void) {
    let body = ["id": userID, "name": userName, "contactInfo": contactInfo, "message": message]
    request(route: .userFeedback, body: body).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<FeedbackResponse>) in

      response.result.ifSuccess({
        completionHandler(response.result.value)
      })

      response.result.ifFailure {
        completionHandler(nil)
      }
    }

  }
```

But i am getting the error like this:
[image: Error screenshot]

What i am doing wrong in this syntax?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the *type could not be inferred* you have to annotate

```
let body : [String:Any] = ["id": userID, "name": userName, "contactInfo": contactInfo, "message": message]
```

or bridge cast it:

```
let body = ["id": userID, "name": userName, "contactInfo": contactInfo, "message": message] as [String:Any]
```

Answer (score 4):

You should add a `[String: Any]` explicit type to the variable.

```
let body: [String: Any] = [
    "id": userID, 
    "name": userName,
    "contactInfo": contactInfo,
    "message": message
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are constructing your post request with mix of data type i.e

1. String
2. Int (You are trying to send id as Int 0)

{
"id": 0,
"name": "string",
"contactInfo": "string",
"message": "string"
}

So, you have to use [String:Any] during declaration. If you don't want to use a casting [String:Any] convert id type Int to String like below.

```
{
      "id": "0",
      "name": "string",
      "contactInfo": "string",
      "message": "string"
}
```

Same error could be occurred if you use one Bool param and others String param.